# Is it possible to lower the terrain of a specific polygon in Mapbox?

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a 3D model of a house with a cellar and I want to load it onto Mapbox. Since the cellar is underground I can't see that part of the model. Is there a way to lower the terrain or the z-axis of a specific part of the map (via a polygon)?

If that is not the case, is there a way to look 'under' the map? So that I can see the cellar.

Example of loading a 3D model I am using:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/

Comment: The obvious solution would be to raise the whole model above the ground.

Comment: @SteveBennett I don't want to create a world where half of my models float in the air. Is there a way to have a negative pitch in Mapbox?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. Have you tried using outline instead https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outline#webgl_postprocessing_outline ? You can also check https://github.com/nagix/mapbox-gl-indoor-map

Comment: @LucasP.Luiz this is such a good solution, especially the indoor map. Thanks I will try this.

Comment: @rebuff, glad I could be of help. I posted it as an answer with more details on how that second lib applies the underground effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible, but you can try using outline in threejs to show things underground: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outline#webgl_postprocessing_outline

You can also see the implementation of https://github.com/nagix/mapbox-gl-indoor-map .

Notice that in https://github.com/nagix/mapbox-gl-indoor-map/blob/master/mapbox-gl-indoor-map.js it uses:

```js
getFloorTranslateY(floorId) {
    const zoomFactor = Math.pow(2, this.getZoom() - 12);
    const pitchFactor = Math.sin(this.getPitch() * Math.PI / 180);

    return isNaN(this.visibleFloorId) ?
        -floorId * zoomFactor * pitchFactor :
        -(floorId - this.visibleFloorId) * zoomFactor * pitchFactor * 10;
}
```

To calculate a "y translation offset" to give the impression of "below the floor".

Then it uses this translate + the extrusion height as a negative value when it adds the layer:

```js
const translate = [0, this.getFloorTranslateY(floorId)];

...

this.addLayer({
    id: `floor-fill-${floorId}`,
    type: 'fill-extrusion',
    source: 'indoor',
    'source-layer': 'indoor_floorplan',
    filter: ['all', floorFilter, ['!', roomFilter]],
    paint: {
        'fill-extrusion-color': COLOR_MAIN,
        'fill-extrusion-opacity': OPACITY_FLOOR * opacity,
        'fill-extrusion-height': (+floorId - FLOOR_IDS[0]) * DELTA, //
        'fill-extrusion-translate': translate,
        'fill-extrusion-translate-anchor': 'viewport'
    }
});
```